# Building a new Drivetrain

Tags: cassette, chainring

I’m looking to build up a new dive train for a slalom / 4x bike.
Is it possible to mix and match any sort of chainring and cassette without running into any problems ?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how broad the perspective you're asking from is, the answer could reasonably be no or yes.

Going by mainstream norms, you're talking about a 1x drivetrain with a narrow-wide ring, and your main setup choice is changuide or not. Extent NW rings are basically compatible with whatever chain you want except Shimano 12, and I don't think there's a scenario where the guide you choose if any informs what ring/chain you can use. So from that perspective, among crank/ring/bb setups that give the right chainline for your rear end, the main other problem you can get into is putting a Shimano 12 chain on a ring that's too wide for it. Other than that it's basically all cross compatible, including Eagle with any narrow-wide as far as I know. (There may be some kind of fringe exception, but it's not common.)

From the perspective of all chainring setups and cassettes ever, yes, there are potential mismatches too numerous to list.

So it depends what you mean, or perhaps more usefully, it depends on whether this is an all new build from a new frame or whether there's older stuff in the mix.